# How to fix OData query returning faulty result although underlying data is correct?

Tags: json, filter, odata

**Platform:**

Blazor, EF Core 6

When sending an OData filter query to my server, it works for some properties and fails for others, although they have the same type.

```cs
    public partial class DocumentRequestDTO
    {
        public DocumentRequestDTO()
        { }

        [Key]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string AuthorID { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Authorname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public Guid DocumentID { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        public string OwnerID { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Ownername { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Filename { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string ReasonForRequest { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string WatermarkText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public bool IsForInternalUse { get; set; } = false;
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public string ReasonForDecision { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Statusname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public List<ProxyTooltipData>? Proxies { get; set; } = null;
        }
    }
```

**Controller code:**

```cs
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<DocumentRequestDTO> GetForSelect(string userID, bool showByAuthor)
    {
        IQueryable<DocumentRequest> qBase = null!;
        try
        { 
            qBase = 
                _context.Requests
                    .Include(r => r.Document)
                        .ThenInclude(d => d.Owner)
                    .Include(r => r.Author)
                    .Where(r => r.TimeStamp.Date >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-ServerGlobals.RequestLifespan))
                    ;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error '{e.Message}' occurred while quyering requests.");
        }

        UserInfo user = _context.UserInfo.FirstOrDefault(e => e.AccountID == userID);

        if ((user != null) && (user.AccessLevel < AccessLevels.Admin))
        {
            try
            {
                if ((user.AccessLevel == AccessLevels.Requester) || showByAuthor)
                {
                    qBase = qBase.Where(x => x.AuthorID == user.AccountID);
                }
                else
                {
                    List<string> proxiedOwners = new();
                    foreach (var p in _context.ProxyInfo.Where(p => p.ProxyID == user.AccountID).ToList())
                        proxiedOwners.Add(p.AccountID);
                    qBase = qBase.Where(x => proxiedOwners.Contains(user.AccountID));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error '{e.Message}' occurred while determining proxied owners.");
            }
        }

        IQueryable<DocumentRequestDTO> qFinal = null!;
        try
        {
            qFinal = qBase
                .Select(
                    x => new DocumentRequestDTO()
                    {
                        ID = x.ID,
                        AuthorID = x.AuthorID,
                        TimeStamp = x.TimeStamp,
                        DocumentID = x.Document.ID,
                        Filename = (x.Document == null) ? "unknown" : x.Document.Filename,
                        OwnerID = x.Document.OwnerID,
                        Ownername = x.Document.Owner.Name,
                        Authorname = x.Author.Name,
                        Description = x.Document.Description,
                        WatermarkText = x.WatermarkText,
                        ReasonForRequest = x.ReasonForRequest,
                        ReasonForDecision = x.ReasonForDecision,
                        IsForInternalUse = x.IsForInternalUse,
                        ReviewStatus = x.ReviewStatus,
                        Statusname = DocumentRequest.StatusName(x.ReviewStatus),
                        Proxies = new()
                    });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error '{e.Message}' occurred while building request result.");
        }

        List<DocumentRequestDTO> l = null!;
        try
        {
            l = qFinal.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error '{e.Message}' occurred while verifying request result.");
        }

        return qFinal;
    }
```

**StatusName code:**

```
public enum RequestStatus
{
    Pending,
    Approved,
    Declined,
    NoDecisionNeeded
}

public class DocumentRequest : PropertyIndexer
{
    public static string StatusName(RequestStatus status)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
            case RequestStatus.Pending:
                return "Pending";

            case RequestStatus.Approved:
                return "Approved";

            case RequestStatus.Declined:
                return "Declined";

            case RequestStatus.NoDecisionNeeded:
                return "No decision needed";

            default:
                return "unknown";
        }
    }
}
```

**Working request:**

```
https://localhost:12345/TestServer/RequestDto
    ?$count=true&$orderby=Ownername&$select=Ownername&userID=0388&showByAuthor=False
```

**Result:**

```
{@odata.context: "https://localhost:44393/DocServer2/$metadata#RequestDto(Ownername)", @odata.count: 4,…}
@odata.context: "https://localhost:44393/DocServer2/$metadata#RequestDto(Ownername)"
@odata.count: 4
    value: [{Ownername: "Baggins, Frodo"}, 
            {Ownername: "Baggins, Frodo"}, 
            {Ownername: "Wonka, Willy"},…]
        0: {Ownername: "Baggins, Frodo"}
        1: {Ownername: "Baggins, Frodo"}
        2: {Ownername: "Wonka, Willy"}
        3: {Ownername: "Wonka, Willy"}
```

**Failed request:**

```
https://localhost:12345/TestServer/RequestDto
    ?$count=true&$orderby=Filename&$select=Filename&userID=0388&showByAuthor=False
```

**Result:**

```
{"@odata.context":"https://localhost:44393/DocServer2/$metadata
 #RequestDto(Filename)",
 "@odata.count":4,"value":[
```

**The underlying data from the controller:** (from the list l)

[image: Data from controller]

The error occurs when selecting Filename or Statusname. I found that when assigning constant values to these properties ("Testfile.pdf" and "Test Status") the error does not appear. However, the data returned from my controller is complete and cointains valid filenames for all records returned, and there are no exceptions thrown during execution of my controller's code; Not even when getting a list of the data from the query result.

Regarding Statusname: If you check my below related code, you will notice that there will always valid string data assigned to it.

Comment: This usually happens when either the controller or the serializer crash due to an error, eg a `null` result for a non-null property. Please post your controller code at least. If you use EF to load the data, can you execute that query at all? Have you tried creating a unit test that calls the controller action directly?

Comment: Which .NET, EF and OData versions are you using? If you use EF 6/7, EF itself can throw an error if a `null` is returned for a non-null property

Comment: The same query that works for Ownername fails for Filename, and each record returned contains a valid Filename. There are no null values in the data, I checked that with the debugger, and you also cannot add data to my database that does not contain a valid filename. Btw, the query also fails for another string property of my data, which also always contains a valid value.

Comment: Yes, it fails because the code threw an exception. Post the code. I use OData too, I've seen this error 100s of times, and the cause is almost always the same - a null property. To find the problem and *avoid* it, you need to first ensure you can read the data - that's done using  a unit test for the DbContext. Then you need to ensure you can return the data, that's where the controller test is needed. Finally you need to ensure the results can be serialized. That's why you need a WebFactory-based integration test

Comment: Yeah. Fun fact: Without the filter, the query returns 100% correct data, plus I checked the query result made in the controller with the debugger, and there were no exceptions. The filter is only processed by OData after my controller returns the data, which then has the exact same shape as one used for getting the data unfiltered. Anyways, I will post the controller code above.

Comment: Which means your controller is crashing, or the filter results in data with nulls. You really need to write the unit tests, especially for serialization problems.

Comment: The controller is not crashing, or it wouldn't work for different filter values (e.g. Ownername, which works). I also put try-catch-blocks around all code blocks in the relevenant controller method. And as I said: I checked the data from the query in the debugger, and it is all fine. I also got it in a list to make sure it could all be retrieved and there were no null values in it. I put this too in a try-catch-block. No exceptions were caught. See the edits to my question.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the data my controller returns. Please let me know whether you can detect any nulls there (I can't).

Comment: Write the unit tests.  I use Blazor WASM too, with OData and EF Core 6. I get such errors too. It really, really depends on the data. I already explained what I did to fix them - write tests for the DbContext, controller *and* OData itself. Looking at the data won't help you find a missed `?` at the 15th text property.

Comment: I have found the cause of the problem myself, and it has nothing to do at all with null values in the data. The reason is much more complicated. See the answer I posted. Btw, I tested whereever I could, but the problem arises in a 3rd party module I cannot debug or unit test.

Comment: The problem has to do with a crash in the controller.  *That's* what I said from the start. Unit tests would have revealed that. Not that it's nulls for sure - that's the easy answer you were looking for. There are no easy answers with OData - you'll have to write unit tests just to be able to isolate the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself: It is the assignment of

```
Statusname = DocumentRequest.StatusName(x.ReviewStatus)
```

in the controller.

When OData tries to retrieve data using the IQueryable my controller returns, it fails to invoke that static class member, because it expects a property from a database table here.

Now the question is whether there is a workaround for that not requring adding database table properties, because I would like to display a user readable version of the data's ReviewStatus property.

Comment: That's not an OData problem, it's an EF Core problem that can be tested with a simple unit test. This would throw an exception that the expression can't be converted to SQL. Had you posted such an exception it would be easy to find out what's wrong. There are a *lot* questions asking how to solve such problems.

Comment: `whether there is a workaround` yes, and there are several duplicates - you *can't* use client-side methods on EF LINQ queries to begin with. You can load the property value as-is in the LINQ query and *then* apply the function. You can apply the function in the property's setter. You could convert `Statusname` to a calculated property calling `DocumentRequest.StatusName`/  Or, instead of mapping directly to the DTO, you can load either the entity or an anonymous object with just the properties you want and map them to the DTO, either manually or using Automapper

Comment: What is `ReviewStatus`? If it's an enum, and `Statusname` is the enum's name, you can remove `Statusname` completely and configure `ReviewStatus` to be serialized as text. Or just leave it as is - if `DocumentRequestDTO` is defined in a Shared project, the WASM code will know what that enum is. It could keep using that enum and only convert it to text, eg using `Enum.GetName` or a format string, when rendering the value as text

Comment: ReviewStatus is an enum (see the code I listed) and Statusname gives a prettified string value for ReviewStatus values (e.g. "NoDecisionNeeded" -> "no decision needed"), because that looks much better when displaying such data to human readers, that's why I didn't want to use Enum.GetName. Due to the peculiarities of some 3rd party software I am using, I cannot call Statusname in some getter of DocumentRequestDTO.

Comment: Why not let pretty printing for Blazor then? You're paying to transfer the same label twice over the wire. . It may not sound much if you retrieve 2 objects from a local server, but this adds up very quickly. Especially when you want to retrieve lots of data eg  to display in a grid, pivot or chart. Besides, you don't *have* to use the exact same class for both the API and Blazor. It's convenient at first but quickly becomes a burden, because anything you add to the client side impacts the server and vice versa